# How to open an expo project in android studio?

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, expo

I wanted to install `react-native-tesseract-ocr` module in my project manually which requires performing certain modifications in android studio. When a project is made using react-native it usually creates a folder for android (named `android`). In expo I can't seem to find any folder such as this. How do I open the project in Android studio and make sure whatever changes I make there stick after I continue developing the project in expo itself?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have native app folders in expo.
If you need so, you need to eject the expo app. It will create both the native app directories and handle other stuff related to it.

Please do read about it before you do so. https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/eject/